# How to reload a whole queryset from db in django?

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

I'm running periodic tasks with celery. One such task gets objects from db with by filter:

```
pages = Page.objects.filter(active=True)
```

initially(before starting celery itself) there are 10 such objects in db with `active=True`. The task executes accordingly when started, on all these 10 objects.

```
from django.db import transaction
from celery.task import task
from celery import group
from .models import Page

#@transaction.atomic
@task()
def check_pages():
    #@transaction.commit()
    pages = Page.objects.filter(active=True) #not updated later
    g = group(page_check.s(page.id) for page in pages)
    g()


#settings.py
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'run-every-1-second': {
        'task': 'tasks.check_pages',
        'schedule': 1.0,
    },
}
```

Now, if I add another `Page` object with `active=True`, this is not recognized or filtered in the task(which is already running periodically).

I know `obj.reload_from_db()`. But that is applicable only to reload an object and not a `<QuerySet>`.

I also tried using `transaction.commit()` with `@transaction.atomic`. But that stops tasks' execution since transaction doesn't work over multiple workers and tasks.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This code wouldn't have the behaviour you describe. Each invocation of `check_pages` would get a fresh queryset from the database. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @DanielRoseman you are right!

Answer (score 9):

Use `all()` method. That make copy of queryset without cached result. Check [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#all)

So you can

```
@task()
def check_pages():
    #@transaction.commit()
    pages = Page.objects.filter(active=True).all() # now it will update later
    g = group(page_check.s(page.id) for page in pages)
    g()
```